# Apply effect to owner Window when child window opens in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

How can apply for example the blur effect when a child Window opens in the XAML?

I am applying this effect when i set the owner of the child window in code behind, but i was looking a way to apply it in the XAML. Is there anything to acomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be to catch a change to the `IsActive` property in a style. The parent window will be deactivated when a child window pops up:

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <BlurEffect Radius="5" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

The drawback with this approach is that the window is also deactivated when you switch away from the application. If this is an issue for you then you're probably better off sticking with the idea of applying the effect in the code-behind when you pop up the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

An small improvement for design-time to the accepted answer is a MultiTrigger. That way one could find a property check that is always true at run time but always false at design time. For instance, the not so well documented ToolTip property.

```html
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsActive" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="ToolTip" Value="A Tooltip"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <BlurEffect/> 
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </MultiTrigger>          
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```